# Bulleted List for .docx in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm having a problem creating a bulleted-list within my document.
I tried the solution from may last year, but it didn't work for me: 
[How to create a bulleted list in Apache POI XWPF Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441238/how-to-create-a-bulleted-list-in-apache-poi-xwpf-document)
I'm able to create the numbered list, but not the one I need.
I'm using the newest nightly version of the Libraries (poi-3.12-beta1) since some of the problems concerning the functioning under Google App Engine are solved in there.
This is how my paragraph's CTP looks like:

```
<w:pPr xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
  <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
  <w:numPr>
    <w:numId w:val="1"/>
  </w:numPr>
</w:pPr>
```

... but even after changing the numId Value to 0, there was no bullets at all, and all the numbers above 1 give the same numbered list. This is how I manually changed the value of numId:

```
CTDecimalNumber ctDecimalNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
ctDecimalNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(2l));
p.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().setNumId(ctDecimalNumber);
```

I'm guessing it has to do something with `<w:numPr>`, can that be changed too?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I did not look into this too much, but wanted to share this link incase it helps: http://officeopenxml.com/WPnumbering.php I use this site whenever I need help sorting through OOXML to figure out the correct structure. This article specifically addresses numbering and bullet points.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad that worked. I posted my response as an answer below. Would you please be able to mark it as the answer to this question? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting and various tests I still wasn't able to create the unordered lists with Apache POI. Seems like this functionality is just gone. 
The only way I was able to use various List-Paragraphs like ordered list/sublist or unordered list/sublist was to manually write these 4 paragraphs at the beginning of the template doc, to **clone** them at the places where i need to use them, and to delete document body elements 1-4 at the end of the document generation.
However, even here there is a slight problem: since all ordered lists in the document are gonna come from same root paragraph, they are all gonna be related and will not start from 1. but from the last list item index:

Example:

1. asd
2. zxc

adasdasdasd dasdasd asdasd fsdfsdfsdfs dfsfsdfs sdefsdfsd sdfsdfsdf
asda adasd asdas dasda asdas asdasd vsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfs

3. sdasd
4. fsdfsdfs